# I want to get record id from the odoo breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-13

i need to get the record id from the odoo breadcrumbs

[image]

I need the recod id of the record "Education event 1" so when i click "Add attendes" buttons i cant pass the record to the method that is called by the button.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Had to get the active_id from a javascript method and pass it using context